# request.timeout.ms and Spring Kafka Synchronous Event Publishing with KafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I'm a bit confused about the best practice for configuring the timeout of an event published synchronously through Spring Kafka.[The Spring Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#examples) provides an example using `ListenableFuture`'s `get(SOME_TIME, TimeUnit)` to enable synchronous publishing of events with a timeout of `SOME_TIME`. (duplicated below for reference).

```
public void sendToKafka(final MyOutputData data) {
    final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = createRecord(data);

    try {
        template.send(record).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        handleSuccess(data);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        handleFailure(data, record, e.getCause());
    }
    catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        handleFailure(data, record, e);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I was looking at [Kafka's Producer Configuration Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) and saw that Kafka had a configuration for `request.timeout.ms`, which was responsible for the below setting in Kafka.

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted.

Would it make more sense to configure `template.send(...).get(...)` with some time unit (e.g., 10 seconds/10,000 ms, as given in the example from Spring Kafka above), or would the better approach be to configure `request.timeout.ms` (along with `retries`) to emulate this behavior through Kafka internally and make a no-args call to `get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use the no-args `get()`; you could hang forever if there was some bug in the client code.

The two timeouts are really different.

The future `get()` is to get the result of the send (success or failure).

If your producer configuration can succeed after the `get()` times out then you can get duplicates (assuming you are retrying at the application level after failure).

I suppose the "best practice" would be to use a `get()` timeout that is greater than `retries * request.timeout.ms` but that could be a long time. But it will ensure that you get the real result of the send. Getting a timeout in that situation should be considered an anomaly that needs investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gary! To clarify a point, when you say "after the `get()` times out then you can get duplicates", are you referring to a scenario with a `get()` timeout `SOME_TIME`  < `retries * request.timeout.ms` (e.g. `SOME_TIME = 1200ms, retries = 2, request.timeout.ms = 1000ms`)? E.g. in the above, after the first retry, the producer resends the send (and it succeeds at some time `t = 1500ms > SOME_TIME`), but before acknowledging the second success of the send, the `SOME_TIME` value for the `get()` call comes into effect and throws a `TimeoutException`, leading to duplication later?

Comment: I mean if you have retries at the application level as well as within the kafka-clients (i.e. call `send()` and `get()` again if you get a timeout on the `get()`). Then, yes, if a retried send at the `kafka-client` level succeeds after the get times out, your application-level retry will cause a duplicate publication. Hence it's best to ensure the get timeout is greater than `retries * request.timeout.ms`.